# A question about the text.css in the 960 Grid System Framework

Tags: css, 960.gs, css-frameworks

I'm currently using the 960 grid system framework for my CSS project and I've decided to work in their suggested text.css file. I notice their suggested font sizes are all in pixels, wouldn't it be better to use percents instead? Why do you think they've gone with pixels?

If you use 960 in your projects, what do you recommend?

Thanks

Comment: It's personal preference, if you decide to you want to use % then go through and change all px values to % :)

Comment: I usually go with `px` and have not used `%` really that much. I suppose the attraction with `%` comes from flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

It's odd, I have always been told to use em for font-size, in regard of portability issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a percentage to define a font, but it's not as precise as utilizing a fixed pixel specification or a fluid em

`font-size:30px;` --> it will always be 30px no matter what
`font-size:2em;` --> it scales up and down if the screen increases or decreases in size

If you are using a fixed-width column layout, which has a total of 960px, hence the name 960 grid, then yes, its easier if you just go for fixed pixel sizes to make sure everything fits fine.

You should experiment using `em` anyway as its quite handy